# May I define two Default string in values directory?

Tags: android, resources, android-resources

My question is: In our country, some **default** words in string.xml as "wifi" must be change to "wlan",but in other country,I should keep "wifi" as the **default** string.xml.
And I don't want fit for it in src code also,because it will cost a lot of time for code maintenance.

NOTICE:I have different default string.xml,in different country

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to [Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html). Where you can easily do you task.

Below content Reference : [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

***To add support for more languages, create additional values directories inside res/ that include a hyphen and the ISO country code at the end of the directory name. For example, values-es/ is the directory containing simple resourcess for the Locales with the language code "es". Android loads the appropriate resources according to the locale settings of the device at run time.***

*Once you’ve decided on the languages you will support, create the resource subdirectories and string resource files. For example:*

> MyProject/
>       res/
>          values/
>              strings.xml
>          values-es/
>              strings.xml
>          values-fr/
>              strings.xml

Add the string values for each locale into the appropriate file.

At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

For example, the following are some different string resource files for different languages.

English (default locale), `/values/strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish, /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

Reference : [Supporting Different Languages](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Comment: I don't think you understood my question? or my english is not very well.:).  My problem is ,I have to use two default string.xml with different strings.

Comment: for example:English (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>`
Spanish, (default locale)/values/strings.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>`

Comment: What is the problem? you have to write as many string's version as you are going to support languages. But at last a string for different countries having the same name which you will use in your code... so whats the problem here?